# Running R script through .bat file on windows 8.1?

Tags: r, windows, batch-file

I'm trying to run a R script through a `.bat` file, and I only managed to open the file and not to run the script.

These lines are what I use in the `.bat` file.

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.3\bin\Rscript.exe" 
"C:\Users\Documents\Script\Script1d.R"  --vanilla  --slave
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It should be one line.

Comment: Thank you @djhurio, that seem to work